# Warning in json (dummy data) to display

Tags: ios, json

Here I used dummy json data and try to display in my table view. But I used to check in the console but its not working. Did I miss Anything?

I should get json like this :

```
[
  {
    "symbol": "ABC",
    "price": 87.86,
    "change": -0.41
  },

  {
    "symbol": "GHI",
    "price": 67.64,
    "change": 0.05
  }
]
```

my code:

```
 NSDictionary *jsonObject = @[@{@"symbol":@"ABC",
                                           @"price":@"87.86",@"change":@"-0.41"},
                                         @{@"symbol":@"GHI",
                                           @"price":@"67.64",@"change":@"0.05"}];


    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

    NSLog(@" JSON DATA \n  %@",[NSString stringWithCString:[jsonData bytes] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

I'm get the warning:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSDictionary *' with an expression of type 'NSArray *'
```

Is this the correct format or did I miss anything?

When i try to change the value it getting `null` in console

EDITED FOR ALL ANSWER:

```
NSArray *jsonObject;
jsonObject = @[@{@"Id1":@"mad",
                 @"people":@"12",@"total":@"20"},
               @{@"Id2":@"normal",
                 @"people":@"13",@"total":@"20"}];


NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

NSLog(@" JSON DATA \n  %@",[NSString stringWithCString:[jsonData bytes] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Comment: You did `@[...]` which is a shorthand syntax for a NSArray, not a NSDictionary. And according to the wanted JSON: Replace ` NSDictionary *jsonObject` with `NSArray *jsonObject`.

Comment: try removing @[] part

Comment: It worked for me. Is `jsonData` `nil`? If yes, try to use a `NSError` for `dataWithJSONObject: options:error:`.

Comment: i am new to ios, please help me out when i remove that i am getting same warning as i mentioned above

Comment: Your above code works if you change the NSDictionary to an NSArray, what are you doing when you try to change the value?

Comment: @JamesP i am changing the key and object only like `@"symbol":@"ABC"` TO `@"symbol":@"pop"` like that if i change i am getting null

Comment: @ Maddey After changing working for me

Comment: @elavarasan SEE MY UPDATED POST UNDER " EDITED FOR ALL POST". i am getting null

Comment: @Maddey show the code where you change the object and it is null.

Comment: @JamesP see my updated post under "edited for all answer". There i changed the object, value ,when i print in console its printing null

Comment: @elavarasan but why its not working for me. i am using xcode 7

Comment: i am using xcode 7.1.1 debug it and check

Comment: @elavarasan yes its worked now .thanks. if possible please try to solve in this post too

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try like this

```
 NSArray *jsonObject;
 jsonObject = @[@{@"symbol":@"ABC",
                               @"price":@"87.86",@"change":@"-0.41"},
                             @{@"symbol":@"GHI",
                               @"price":@"67.64",@"change":@"0.05"}];


NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

NSLog(@" JSON DATA \n  %@",[NSString stringWithCString:[jsonData bytes] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Comment: Why do you alloc init jsonObject, then immediately reassign it?

Comment: @James P Please check it now

Comment: It works for me, but it's no different to the code in the original question.

Comment: yes its worked only one time. after if i change my kev value or object name its showing null

Comment: @ Maddey when you are changing values and where you are doing the changes